# `vimdiff` nor `nvim -d` are working as an external diff tool for git

Tags: command-line, vimdiff, git

First line says output is not a terminal. The rest of the output looks like term codes aren't being processed.

I use st, with $TERM = st-256color. I just tried it on termite ($TERM = xterm-termite) with the same screen.

```
parmort • 1d
```

I went and set diff.external=vimdiff and it displays the text above (after running just git diff). I've also tried nvim (through diff.external=nvim -d). Any thoughts

[image: Error messages]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried

```
git config --global diff.tool vimdiff3
git config --global difftool.vimdiff3.path nvim
git config --global merge.tool vimdiff3
git config --global mergetool.vimdiff3.path
```

It worked like a charm.

Comment: Thank you!  Worked perfectly